# In Matlab how to find height of an object in Binary images

Tags: image, matlab, binary, height

[image: Binary Image]

I cropped an Image and converted it to a Binary image. Now How do I calculate the Height of that cropped part. I.e How to find the height of that Black part alone.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum height?

Comment: @nikaltipar what do maximum height return. could you elaborate it?

Comment: For example, I'd say the maximum height is somewhere around in the middle of that image

Comment: [Image](http://imgur.com/K1NdqGN)
I want the height of that red line. I don't know how maximum height would do that ?

Comment: @nikaltipar How does maximum height work?